# Does every transitive permutation group contain a permutation whose cycle lengths have a common divisor?

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

Let $H$ be a transitive subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_n$, $n \geq 2$.
Using Jordan's lemma ($H$ is not a union of conjugate proper subgroups), we see that $H$ contains a permutation without fixed points.
I'm interested in whether $H$ necessarily contains a permutation whose cycle lengths have a common divisor.
It's tricky to either prove or disprove this: on the one hand, my attempts at proving this have all been vain (some cases are easy: if $H$ embeds via its action on itself, if $H$ is a $p$-group ; if $n$ is a prime power we can reduce to the $p$-group case by noticing that any $p$-Sylow of $H$ acts itself transitively); on the other hand, a colleague of mine has checked that this is true for $2 \leq n \leq 27$ using Julia (assuming correctness of his code).
A key observation based on his experimentations is that you cannot choose which of the prime divisors of $n$ divides the cycle lengths of an element (there is a transitive subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_6$ with no elements having only even-sized cycles, and a transitive subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_{12}$ with no elements having only cycles of length a multiple of three, so neither the smallest nor the largest prime dividing $n$ are always candidates for example).

Thanks for any opinion about this question ☺

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a theorem of Fein, Kantor and Schacher that every finite transitive permutation group of degree at least two contains a derangement of prime power order, and hence all the cycle lengths are divisible by the prime.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, this is perfect. A funny thing is that I encountered the question while studying Brauer groups, and now I'm learning that the theorem was proved with a similar idea in mind. Makes it sound like this is an "unnatural question" to ask about permutation groups outside of the context of division algebras :p

Comment: The question of whether or not a transitive permutation group always contains a derangement of prime order was independently raised in graph theory.

Comment: Definition: derangement = permutation with no fixed point.(For those who, like me, were not aware of this term.)

Comment: Note: this apparently stronger statement is actually equivalent to the required statement. Indeed, let $f$ be a permutation in the group, all of whose cycles have size divisible by some prime $p$, and among them, chosen with a maximal number of cycles. If by contradiction $q$ is another prime dividing some cycle length, then $f^q$ has the same property and has more cycles, a contradiction. So $f$ has $p$-power order.